# Cross-browser bookmark sync?

Tags: firefox, sync, google-chrome, bookmarks

Is there a way for me to sync bookmarks between Firefox and Chrome on several different Ubuntu machines?

Edit: Even willing to run something on my own web server if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[XMark](http://www.xmarks.com/) does what you want very well. I used it across multiple machines, multiple platforms, multiple browsers. Standard features are free. There's a premium version that supports mobile devices (iPhone, Android, Blackberry etc...).

Comment: I heard X-Marks was dead / dying.  Any truth to that?

Comment: OK -- found out they were ready to shut down the company and somebody with a business model in mind bought them.  However, they seem to be having serious problems:  http://getsatisfaction.com/foxmarks/topics/same_old_duplicates_problem_at_least_make_it_easier_to_fix

Comment: I decided to try it out for myself and I am glad that I did.  It does have some quirks and some flakiness for sure, but if you know how syncing systems work, you can deal with it.   The part that sold me on this was their support for sync profiles which lets me sync only what I need to my various computers and work/home/remote/mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use Delicious for that:

http://delicious.com/

There are plugins both for Chrome and Firefox.

If you don't like your bookmarks to be public, you can mark them as private (or at least you could before, I haven't used for a long time).

Comment: The plugins for Firefox and Chrome are pretty nice.  This also supports Android, costs nothing, and can be kept private.  FTW

Comment: After a week of playing with Delicious I had to let it go.  The Firefox add-on was a big flaky, but the real killer was the lack of a decent Chrome add-on.   I tried every Chrome one there was, but they were all pretty weak.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't... Chrome synchronizes with the Google servers, Firefox with the Firefox servers (or your own server, but I've never tried it)... You can sync Firefox with Ubuntu One, but then again it won't affect Chrome.

I tried to get this working myself, but so far came up empty. But if anyone knows a not-too-complicated way, please do not hold back. :)

Comment: I am right there with you...

Comment: I would just like to note that Chrome sync for bookmarks has a serious limitation that FF sync doesn't.  FF sync account data is held separately from the browser cookies, thus you can run multiple firefox profiles that all sync to the same server.  In Chrome you cannot.  If you make use of the new sync-to-chrome user profiles (which are very cool) then you cannot share bookmarks with your other profiles.  A deal killer for using Chrome sync for bookmarks for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to sync between Firefox and Chrome, **you can use Google Bookmarks and the GMarks add-on for Firefox**. Just put your current bookmarks in Chrome into Google Bookmarks, and then when using Firefox, install the [GMarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gmarks/) add-on. GMarks will allow you to use your Google Bookmarks in Firefox.

**Another alternative could be using [Netvouz](http://www.netvouz.com/)**.

> Netvouz is a social bookmarking service that allows you to save your
>   favorite links online and access them from any computer, wherever you
>   are. Organize your bookmarks in folders and tag each bookmark with
>   keywords. Access them quickly on your own personalized bookmarks page.

Netvouz allows you to create a neat little bookmarks page that you can easily access no matter what web browser you use to always have your bookmarks at hand.

Comment: Good stuff.  By the way, Chrome bookmark sync uses Google Docs now and not Googgle bookmarks (insane, yes?) and so I wonder how long Google Bookmarks will be supported.

Comment: I spotted my Chrome bookmarks in Google Docs a while back, before the whole interface change. Now I can't find them anymore. Any idea  where they could be within Google Docs?

Comment: Hate to necro a thread, but GMarks is no longer compatible with the newer versions of FF ("Quantum").