# Can I sync bookmarks between Firefox and Chromium?

Tags: firefox, sync, chromium

So, Firefox has turned so resource intensive that my netbook can't run it without making me want to pull my hair out. Thus, I have been trying Chromium with quite some success (I have managed to find proper equivalents for my firefox plugins), the only thing I'm lacking is my bookmarks, which are stored in my Firefox Sync account. Point is **I don't want to use Google Bookmarks**, mostly because of the whole thing with encryption.

Is there any way to use Firefox Sync with Chromium?, or is there any secure alternative?

Comment: If you are fully switching to Chromium and don't have other devices you want sync'd, you could just import your bookmarks. (Wrench -> Bookmarks -> Import bookmarks and settings)

Comment: That's not the case, I wouldn't have asked otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser bookmark sync?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86236/cross-browser-bookmark-sync)

Comment: Infact i add it on my answer,but here there are more infos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sync bookmarks between [multiple installation of **Firefox**](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/sync/) or [multiple installation of **Chrome/Chromium**](http://youtu.be/hQuXxOBJwSg), but you can't sync them togheter.

You should use **third-party addon/service** like [xmarks.com](http://www.xmarks.com/):

- Visit My Xmarks, register your credentials and log in with your Xmarks username and password.
- Open your browser, and install the addon http://download.xmarks.com/download
- Now open up the Xmarks settings dialog in your browser (Tools > Xmarks > Xmarks Settings...) and configure your login data.
- Xmarks, on each browser you use, will seamlessly keep your bookmarks, (and optionally) passwords and open tabs in sync.

Nothing is transmitted unencrypted through the plugin if you don't want to. You can adjust the encryption level yourself. Passwords are encrypted with your pin anyway, even if you choose to transmit the file unencrypted. If you don't trust it, then simply [don't use the password sync](https://getsatisfaction.com/foxmarks/topics/is_encryption_supported).

More info in [this question too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86236/cross-browser-bookmark-sync).

Comment: The idea of this website is not to post links of google, but to provide an answer HERE. Ideally, a step-by-step guide with screenshots, if applicable.

Comment: I have improved that

Comment: Do you happen to know whether bookmarks are or not encrypted in their servers? there seems to be nothing about that in the website.

Comment: I have answered directly on editing my answer

Comment: The problem itself isn't only the transmission, I care more about the data itself as it reaches the server, as I don't want anyone looking through my bookmarks.

Comment: It's all encrypted on the server. See documentation. However i think that i have answered you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple tutorial which you will find useful, to setup Xmark on Chrome as well as firefox.

In your Firefox browser go to Tools > Addons > Get Addons. 
[image: Xmark1.png]

Search for Xmarks. 
[image: Xmark2]

Click on Install button. 
[image: Xmark3]

It will ask to restart your browser. Click on Restart.
[image: Xmark4]

Now go to Tools > Xmark > Xmark Setting
[image: Xmark6]

Click on Run Setup Wizard
[image: Xmark7]
[image: Xmark8]

In the Log in to Xmarks window click on Create an account for new account
[image: Xmark9]

Fill up the require details and click on Create Account button
[image: Xmark10]

Enter your computer name
[image: Xmark12]

If you want to synchronize your browser history click on Enable synchronization of browser history
[image: Xmark13]

Enable the appropriate options you want in next screen
[image: Xmark14]

Xmark will automatically start synchronizing your data.
[image: Xmark15]

After completing all the steps successfully you will get the success windows.
[image: Xmark16]

Now open Chrome Browser and install Xmark plugin.

After installation you will get Xmark icon on the right hand side of your browser.
[image: Xmark17]

In the Xmark setting window click on Run Setup Wizard
[image: Xmark 18]

Click on Next button to start the configuration part
[image: Xmark19]

We will use the techienote.com@gmail.com account which we have created earlier to sync the the data. Click on Log me in radio option.
[image: Xmark20]

Fill require details.
[image: Xmark21]

It will check your login with their servers
[image: Xmark22]

Click on the Change Sync Setting button
[image: Xmark23]

I choose Merge bookmarks with server, starting with the server, as I also want to synchronize chorme bookmarks
[image: Xmark24]

Click on Sync Button, to start the synchronization.
[image: Xmark23]

After successful configuration it will show you merge complete message.
[image: Xmark25]
[image: Xmark26]

If you want to secure your data transmission you have to encrypt it. To do so go to Xmark Settings > Advanced and select Encryption to Encrypt All.
[image]

Thanks.
[Reference](http://www.techienote.com/2012/03/sync-bookmarks-across-different-browser-ubuntu.html)