# Problem importing Firefox bookmarks to Chromium

Tags: firefox, sync, chromium

I would like to switch from Firefox to Chromium (it seems to be faster for my system) and I have a large number of bookmarks I would like to import into Chromium. I looked at this question: [Can I sync bookmarks between Firefox and Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110274/can-i-sync-bookmarks-between-firefox-and-chromium) but that seemed to be specific to Firefox Sync, which I don't have. I just want to import my bookmarks from Firefox into Chromium.

However, when I go to the Customize and Control button and then choose the option `Import Bookmarks and Settings` under the `Bookmarks` menu item, it gives me this:

[image: No supported browser found]

I have Firefox and Chromium as up to date as the official repositories (I believe), so I really have no clue what is going on.

I have attempted to import directly from HTML, but it only imports the first set of bookmarks, nothing beyond that (where all of the bookmarks I *really* want are.)

Can I import the JSON Firefox backup file into Chromium, or am I stuck manually entering all of these bookmarks into Chromium?

Thanks!

**EDIT: 10/30/2013**
I'm going to attempt `sudo apt-get upgrade` to see if this does anything.

**EDIT: Later in 10/30/2013**
Nope. It only upgrade LightDM:

> The following packages will be upgraded:  
>   liblightdm-gobject-1-0
>   lightdm 2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

**EDIT: 10/31/2013**
Turns out I mis-read the Ubuntu PPA. 13.04, Raring Ringtail, only has 28.0. Apparently I am to be forced to upgrade if I want software upgrades. Botheration.

I guess I will do so when I can, but does anyone know if I can force an upgrade of only certain software (Chromium for example.)

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you can use xmarks :). A note : don't enable xmarks & chrome bookmarks sync to google.

Comment: @Web-E I looked at that in the post I linked to. I don't really want to sign up for *another* online account/service I have to keep track of. I'm looking for within my own computer fixes, though thanks anyways!

Comment: Looks like this could be a recurrence of an old bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/918371 Seems to happen if the version of Firefox is to new for Chromium. There seems to be suggestions at the time that downgrading Firefox may solve the issue. Is ok for me with version 25 of Firefox and version Version 29.0.1547.65 Ubuntu 13.10 for Chromium in 13.10

Comment: @ChrisCarter Hrm. I have Chromium 28.28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu 13.04. I believe all of my software is up to date, is Chromium 29.0 installed from elsewhere than the default repositories?

Comment: @ChrisCarter I believe the official Ubuntu PPA has Chromium 29.0, as per this page https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser, but I, fully up to date according to update manager, still have Chromium 29.0. Is this because I have 13.04 instead of 13.10?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Chances are 13.04 will have an older version than 13.10. I can't be fully certain if it is the same problem but I wouldn't rule it out.

Comment: @ChrisCarter Your comment made me look twice. I forgot that I have Raring Ringtail (13.04) instead of Saucy Salamander (I mistook the second option as being the second-most recent release). That is my problem. Raring Ringtail only has Chromium 28.0. I guess I have to upgrade. Uggh. That is very annoying. Is there any way I can force an upgrade?

Comment: Looks like it is easier to downgrade firefox http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/how-to-install-previous-versions-of-firefox-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/ than it is to upgrade Chromium http://askubuntu.com/questions/89058/how-to-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-chromium

Comment: @ChrisCarter I turns out that downgrading to firefox 24 doesn't help at all. I guess I have to upgrade to 13.10 to get this working . Oh well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated Ubuntu (not upgraded, I still have 13.04) and Chromium updated to `30.0.1599.114 (Developer Build 30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.04.2) Ubuntu 13.04` and I can now import from Firefox!

Thanks to @ChrisCarter for attempting to help me solve my issue, update did it!